# How to send a message on the bot startup to every server it is in?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to send an announcement to all the servers my bot is in. I found this on GitHub, but it requires a server ID and a channel ID.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    server = bot.get_server("server id")
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel("channel id"), "Test")
```

I found a similar question, but it is in discord.js. It says something with default channel, but when I tried this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.send_message(discord.Server.default_channel, "Hello everyone")
```

it gave me this error:

```
Destination must be Channel, PrivateChannel, User, or Object
```

Answer (score 7):

First, to answer your question about `default_channel`: Since about June 2017, Discord no longer defines a "default" channel, and as such, the `default_channel` element of a server is usually set to `None`.

Next, by saying `discord.Server.default_channel`, you're asking for an element of the class definition, not an actual channel. To get an actual channel, you need an instance of a server.

Now, to answer the original question, which is to send a message to every channel, you need to find a channel in the server that you can actually post messages in:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    for server in bot.servers: 
        # Spin through every server
        for channel in server.channels: 
            # Channels on the server
            if channel.permissions_for(server.me).send_messages:
                await bot.send_message(channel, "...")
                # So that we don't send to every channel:
                break
```

Comment: It works kinda. It only sends the message to one server. Do I need to loop it?