# Create Server using Discord Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

If we look at the `Guild Create` event in the discord dev documentation, we see the following:
[image]

I have a couple of questions about this. First of all, I am not sure exactly when I can create a server using a bot account. Following the "when a user is initially connecting" section, I attempted to place the server creation into the `on_ready` function, like so:

```
import discord
import asyncio

import bot.client.getkey as _getkey
from bot.utils import get_owner

class ImABot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        ts = await self.create_server("test")
        inv = await self.create_invite(ts.default_channel)
        await self.send_message(get_owner()) #get owner simply gets the user who owns the bot, me.
Bot = ImABot()


Bot.run(_getkey.key())
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/edl/Desktop/ /Programming/Github/Democracy-Bot/demobot/client/client.py", line 22, in on_ready
    inv = await self.create_invite(ts.default_channel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 2628, in create_invite
    data = yield from self.http.create_invite(destination.id, **options)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I assume this means the server was not created. I hope someone can give me information on when creating a server will work, and whether or not it is possible in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: The error in your code is coming from the fact that [servers are no longer created with a default channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48078278/6779307). So `server.default_channel` is set to `None` for these new servers.

Answer (score 0):

Guilds no longer have default channels, so it is best to avoid using them.

To get the first created channel for the server, your best bet is to use

```
discord.utils.get(new_server.channels, type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

Or if you use discord.py rewrite, then

```
new_server.text_channels[0]
```

Then you can create the invite from that channel.